# I want to remove all BLOBs from a table - set to NULL or EMPTY_BLOB?

Tags: oracle, blob

I want to remove all BLOBs from an Oracle table that are older than a certain date. I was thinking of running a query like this:

```
update blob_table set blob_column = NULL where date_column < some_date;
```

Is it OK to use NULL, or should I really be setting them to EMPTY_BLOB, e.g.:

```
update blob_table set blob_column = EMPTY_BLOB() where date_column < some_date;
```

Comment: I highly recomend to use EMPTY_BLOB. You can read definition, why to do so: http://psoug.org/definition/EMPTY_BLOB.htm

Comment: [Tom Kyte](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:122614800346142639#125051100346783156): it depends on the needs of the application - does it need an "empty file ready to accept data" or does it need "the absence of a file"? From your description is sounds like null might be appropriate, but you might have code that expects a value and will trip over a null.

Comment: @AlexPoole hmm good point. I will check whether any code is reliant upon there being a value in that column.